# Mutual exclusion

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutual-exclusion

I have an application which uses a collection, in this case a queue, from different threads. An object gets enqueued in one thread while another gets dequeued in a different thread.

These actions might occur simultaneously which would resolve in an exception such as argument out of range exception, when the collections counter is being redefined.

I'm looking for a "good looking" and right why to exclude these actions from one another.

1. what I mean by "good looking" is that I don't want to create my own collection derived from this one which includes a lock(object) mechanism
2. I don't want to use the brain storming idea I had, which is pretty "ugly"

```cs
    enqueueOk = false;
    while (!enqueueOk)
    {
           try
           {
               Qsockets.Enqueue(currentSoc);
               enqueueOk = true;
           }
           catch { } 
    }
```

I thought of course using the a lock or a mutex but that would be the case only if I wrap these actions in a procedure which would be called from each thread, and decide either to enqueue or dequeue which would also be long and "ugly"

edit:
because no one seems to see my answer down below

I just used the lock mechanism on the collection itself

```cs
lock(Qsockets)
{
   Qsockets.Enqueue(currentSoc); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a classic Producer-Consumer scenario. Have you check this nice [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Topic under that link is obsolete and there's no information about it now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the TPL? ConcurrentQueue automatically handles concurrent activity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: ... by using locks. I don't think the OP is going to avoid the lock statement, whether explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Agreed. He doesn't necessarily say "no locks." He just wants a "good looking" solution. This problem has been solved. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You always have the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) Class from .Net 4, if .Net 4 is an option. Which implements locking inside the class.

Comment: sorry .Net 3.5 is as high as it goes where i need to check this thing out.
10x for the info

Comment: ReactiveExtensions library is written in 3.5 and includes these classes if I am not mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Concurrent Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) or [Synchronise the queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a ConcurrentQueue (available in 4.0).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The lock statement is the go-to way to handle these things, and "thread-safe" collections built into the .NET Framework rely on them. Just do it.

Comment: i dont think the lock statment works in this case,ive tryed locking 
the same object over various threads and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

i just concluded from a post in bytes ,
that i could just lock the actual collection

lock(Qsockets)
{ 
  Qsockets.Enqueue(currentSoc); 
}